# How to create such a figure using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I have a matrix with many zero elements. The column names are labeled on the horizontal axis. I'd like to show explictly the nonzero elements as the bias from the vertical line for each column.

So how should construct a figure such as the example using ggplot2?

An example data can be generated as follow:

```
set.seed(2018)
N <- 5
p <- 40
dat <- matrix(0.0, nrow=p, ncol=N)
dat[2:7,   1] <- 4*rnorm(6)
dat[4:12,  2] <- 2.6*rnorm(9)
dat[25:33, 3] <- 2.1*rnorm(9)
dat[19:26, 4] <- 3.3*rnorm(8)
dat[33:38, 5] <- 2.9*rnorm(6)
colnames(dat) <- letters[1:5]

print(dat)
```

Comment: Your data should be order in columns tissue/organ (x axis), time (y axis) and value. Put a geom_bar and geom_vline or geom_hline in somewhere. Et voila. You could think of this plot as a horizontal barplot, but flipped (coord_flip).

Comment: You should post some sample data to give potential SO respondents something to work with!

Comment: In this issue, any matrix with column names can be served as s sample data, so I didnot provide data.  Would you show me a simple procedure? I will modify the details. @MauritsEvers

Comment: @zengchao As general advice you want to make it as easy as possible for people to give help. That includes some minimal sample data that we can copy&paste to get started. Most of us like playing around with code, but it's a huge waste of time if we have to come up with random data ourselves only to find out later that it is in fact not representative of your situation. So I recommend spending some time improving your question by adding sample data.

Comment: Thanks your advice. Example data has been added into the question. Plz check it. @MauritsEvers

Comment: What have you tried so far for plotting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be much easier if you can provide some sample data. Thus I needed to create them and there is no guarantee that this will work for your purpose.

```
set.seed(123)

# creating some random sample data
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:100, each = 3),
                 x = rnorm(300),
                 group = rep(letters[1:3], each = 100),
                 bias = sample(0:1, 300, replace = T, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)))

# introducing bias
df$bias <- df$bias*rnorm(nrow(df))              

# calculate lower/upper bias for errorbar
df$biaslow <- apply(data.frame(df$bias), 1, function(x){min(0, x)})
df$biasupp <- apply(data.frame(df$bias), 1, function(x){max(0, x)})
```

Then I used kind of hack to be able to print groups in sufficient distance to make them not overlapped. Based on group I shifted bias variable and also lower and upper bias.

```
# I want to print groups in sufficient distance
df$bias <- as.numeric(df$group)*5 + df$bias
df$biaslow <- as.numeric(df$group)*5 + df$biaslow
df$biasupp <- as.numeric(df$group)*5 + df$biasupp
```

And now it is possible to plot it:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, col = group)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = biaslow, ymax = biasupp), width = 0) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 5, col = "a")) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 10, col = "b")) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 15, col = "c")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(5, 10, 15), labels = letters[1:3])
```

[image]

#### EDIT:

To incorporate special design you can add

```
theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

to your plot.

[image]

#### EDIT2:

To incorporate several horizontal lines, you can create different dataset:

```
df2 <- data.frame(int = unique(as.numeric(df$group)*5), 
                  gr = levels(df$group))
```

And use

```
geom_hline(data = df2, aes(yintercept = int, col = gr))
```

instead of copy/pasting `geom_hline` for each group level.

Comment: Thanks your help. The codes work well. However, I have a bit many columns to depict(more than 30),  so is there any effecient method to add the geom_hline(...) ? I mean that how to avoid add each group by hand?

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option using `facet_wrap` and `geom_col` with `theme_minimal`.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    gather(key, value, -row) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = row, y = value, fill = key)) +
    geom_col() +
    facet_wrap(~ key, ncol = ncol(dat)) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

---

To further increase the aesthetic similarity to the plot in your original post we can

1. move the facet strips to the bottom,
2. rotate strip labels,
3. add "zero lines" in matching colours,
4. remove the `fill` legend, and
5. get rid of the x & y axis ticks/labels/title.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    gather(key, value, -row) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = row, y = value, fill = key)) +
    geom_col() +
    geom_hline(data = dat %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        gather(key, value) %>%
        count(key) %>%
        mutate(y = 0),
        aes(yintercept = y, colour = key), show.legend = F) +
    facet_wrap(~ key, ncol = ncol(dat), strip.position = "bottom") +
    coord_flip() +
    guides(fill = FALSE) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        strip.text.x = element_text(angle = 45),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]